# specifying numbers bigger than long double in cython

Tags: python, c, cython

I have written a function in **cython** that uses `exp` function from `math.h` library of `c`. Since the input of the exponential function is `x=222442.837696` value and the function is supposed to return `exp(-x)` ,it just returns `0.0`. I have defined the input values of the math library as following:

```
cdef extern from "math.h":
    long double exp(double) nogil
    double log(double) nogil
    double atanh(double) nogil
    double sqrt(double) 
    double atan(double) nogil
    double atan2(double, double) 
    double sin(double x) 
    double cos(double x) 
    double fabs(double x)
    double pow(double,double)
```

The function which is part of a bigger class is

```
def MassFunction(self, z, mass):
    #Halo mass function based on Evrard et al. 2002
    cdef double a= 0.281
    cdef double b= 0.0123
    cdef double sigma_f=0.578
    cdef double log_sigma=-log(sigma_f)+a*log(mass)+b*log(mass)*log(mass)
    cdef double alpha= a+2*b*log(mass)
    return (0.315*self.rho_m(z)/mass)*alpha*exp(-1*pow(fabs(log_sigma+0.61),3.8))*self.comoving_volume(z)
```

How could I avoid geting zero value for the exponential function?

Comment: I believe the smallest non-zero number a double can represent is `10^-308`. But `e^-222442` is a lot smaller than that, so I don't see any way to avoid getting zero while using C doubles.

Comment: @user3386109 Well, this value is equivalent of `308*np.log(10)=709.196`, which is much smaller than `222442`.

Comment: Yes, but as `x` increases `exp(-x)` decreases. So `x=709` is the **largest** value of `x` where `exp(-x)` is not zero. Any value of `x` greater than `709` will result in 0.

Comment: Actually, by experimentation, the limit is 745 (most likely due to the use of denormalized numbers).  Try this code: `for (double x = 700; x <= 800; x++) { double y = exp(-x); printf("e^-%.0f = %e\n", x, y); }`

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to avoid getting a `0.0` for `exp(-2.2e5)` for 64 bit (or even 128 bit) floats. What сan be done here is,

- Use a library for arbitrary precision arithmetics such as GMP, but you will probably lose in performance in this case.
- Rewrite your final expression by hand to calculate the logarithm of the mass, and then apply the exponential function. That will solve your problem, assuming the result of the `MassFunction` is within a reasonable range (e.g. between `1e-99` and `1e99`).